# How to make java stand alone application, open with web browser?

Tags: java, browser

I'm creating a web application. In my application, I need to create my admin panel as stand alone application. I need to open application in web browser? Is it possible to do? If it is, How to do it? I'm using SOAP as my web service.

Comment: Batter to use web based framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[Java - URL Processing](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_url_processing.htm)**

Example : `URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/myapplication/firstpage/");`

Or you can open web page via command line :

```
  Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process proc = rt.exec("start http://localhost:8080/myapplication/firstpage/");
```